# A measure theory book with lots of examples

Tags: measure-theory, book-recommendation

I find that when learning more abstract concepts, it helps to have a 'simple' example tied to every theorem in order to fully appreciate the theorem or property.

However, the course notes I am currently using for my studies of Measure Theory (this is a first course for me) do not have many examples. It is highly rigorous and detailed, but lacks examples.

Are you aware of any introductory books on Measure Theory that has a good number of examples tied to each theorem? In other words I guess, do you know of very 'gentle' books on this topic?

Comment: I own one book written by James Yeh of UC Irvine, and it is very good book for those students who struggle and juggle with the subject. "Royden" and "Folland" and for those who "already knew" the topics.

Comment: Rich Bass has a nice (freely available online) book made for a first course for graduate students in measure theory: http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/real.html

Comment: R Bartle's *Introduction to Measure theory*, and Wheeden/Zygmund are both very readable, IMHO.

Comment: I would suggest the Stein and Shakarchi series, book 3: Measure, Integration and Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually refer the books 'Measure theory and Integration' by G De Barra and 'An Introduction to Measure and Integration' by Inder K. Rana which are having a number of examples and exercise problems.